# Flutter - Bloc 8 how to upload video to Firebase

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

How to do update my ui with an emit using bloc.

*I have this in my recipeRepository*

```
  Future<UploadTask> uploadVideo(File file) async {
    final fileName = basename(file.path);
    final destination = 'videos/$fileName';
    final ref = storage.ref(destination);
    final task = ref.putFile(file);
    return task;
  }
```

Inside my recipe bloc, I have this addRecipe that I want to watch the uploading progress and update the UI accordingly.

```
  Future<void> addRecipe(
    AddRecipe event,
    Emitter<RecipeState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      final uploadTask = await _recipeRepository.uploadVideo(event.file);

      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
        final progress = event.bytesTransferred / event.totalBytes;
        emit(UploadingVideo(progress: progress));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      emit(_Error(e.toString()));
    }
  }
```

I this is where I'm watching the state change

```
 final state = context.watch<RecipeBloc>().state;

   return state.maybeWhen(
      uploadingVideo: (progress) {
        return _buildVideoUploading(progress);
      },
      orElse: () => _buildForm(context),
    );
```

```
  Stack _buildVideoUploading(double progress) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: progress,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          (progress * 100).toInt().toString() + '%',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The problem is when the emit code gets called inside the RecipeBloc I get the following error.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':
package:bloc/src/emitter.dart:1
emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
ensure the event handler has not completed.
  **BAD**
  on<Event>((event, emit) {
    future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
  });
  **GOOD**
  on<Event>((event, emit) async {
    await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event is ending before the file has a chance to upload, you need await until the full stream releases its values.

There might be an API to know, I don't know the API, but if there isn't you can always just await the stream itself:

```
final uploadTask = await _recipeRepository.uploadVideo(event.file);
try {
  uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
    final progress = event.bytesTransferred / event.totalBytes;
    emit(UploadingVideo(progress: progress));
  });
  await uploadTask.snapshotEvents.last; // so that the event doesn't end before the stream
}
```